# Linking a 3rd party static library into another static library

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to create a static library that will link to a 3rd party static lib. 
Currently the error I'm receiving is

> No rule to make target `.../libqqrcLib.a', needed by libqqrcAPI.a

**This was solved by updating to a newer version of the NDK that supports working with prebuilt libraries (5b)**

Here is the Android.mk I'm using:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := qqrcLib  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libqqrc.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/coreLib/include

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/qqrc/ 
LOCAL_MODULE    := qqrcAPI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := qqrcEngineImpl.cpp 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := qqrcLib

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Basically I have a qqrc.a static library that I've declared a module for it "qqrcLib".
I want to be able to link it to a second module called "qqrcAPI" (It is being referenced in qqrcEngineImpl.cpp)
It is important to have it in this 2 libraries format since the libqqrc.a is compiled using a different approach.

Also imporant to state that I defined an Application.mk that looks like this:

```
APP_MODULES      := qqrcAPI 
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(call my-dir)./..
```

In order to be able to create a static library. (otherwise I got no output..)

**The current issue** for me is that even though I have a separate module for the prebuilt library and it seems to compile, I can't produce a combined static library that will hold the prebuilt lib in it.
I have in obj\local\armeabi directory the prebuilt library (qqrcLib.a) and the new formed static library (qqrcAPI.a), but it seems that it wasn't linked because the new module is too small...

What am I doing wrong?

help? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use static libraries and JNI. The top level library that you're going to use as your JNI needs to be shared.

As far as I understand the issue, when you add a static library to another static library the second library `.a` file doesn't include all of the first library, i.e. you still need to link both `.a` files to make the `.so` (or other actual executable).

There must be some thing that you're actually trying to make use of these libraries in? I think the solution to your problem comes from whatever that next step is (probably a `.so` shared library).

Comment: Your observation is correct. I'm trying to take advantage of the NDK build system in order to produce a static library that I can give out as an API. I was hoping to be able to avoid using .so file, but unfortunately I can't.